# How to sort String alphabetically in F#?

Tags: arrays, string, sorting, f#, char

I have `string` "DBCA" and want sort it in F#

```
let sortedString str =
    ...

printfn "%A" <| sortedString "DBCA" // "ABCD"
```

Code sample on C#

```
String
    .Concat(
        _str
            .OrderBy(ch => ch)
    );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
open System

let sortedString (str : string) = str |> Seq.sort |> String.Concat
```

Comment: If you for some reason don't want to open System or use System.String but instead use F# String you can do this:

`"bca" |> Seq.sort |> Seq.map string |> String.concat ""`

Answer (score 1):

Solution with LINQ

```
open System
open System.Linq

let orderBy f xs = Enumerable.OrderBy(xs, new Func<_,_>(f))

let sortedString (str:string) =
    str 
    |> List.ofSeq
    |> orderBy (fun ch -> ch)
    |> String.Concat
```

I had this solution, but above answer is better